# What is the meaning of $A+B$ when $A$ and $B$ are two finite fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, coding-theory

I have read such a statement: let $\mathbb K$ be a function field of one variable over the finite field $\mathbb F$. Let $f(x)=x^p-x$, $p$ being the characteristic of $\mathbb K$. Then there is some statement about $f\mathbb K+\mathbb F$, but I don't know what the author means by this. I guess it is a stupid question, but I am a physics student and not very familiar with abstract algebra. Can anyone help?

Comment: It is the set of elements of the form $f(x) \cdot g(x)+a$, where $g(x) \in \mathbb K$ and $a \in \mathbb{F}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Gary Should probably convert that to an answer, since it seems to have answered the OP fully :).

Comment: This is a bit mysterious actually. Presumably $x$ is some element of $\Bbb{K}$, transcendental over $\Bbb{F}$. Hence $f$ is a non-zero element of $\Bbb{K}$. Implying that $f\Bbb{K}$ is just all of $\Bbb{K}$ (fields don't have non-trivial ideals). So I suspect that something essential is left out from the question. Or, whoever wrote this meant something else. We need a bit more context.

Comment: I mean, it must be the case that $f\Bbb{K}+\Bbb{F}$ is the set of elements of the form $fg+a$ with $g$ ranging over $\Bbb{K}$ and $a$ over $\Bbb{F}$. But this is trivially the same set as $\Bbb{K}$. Unless possibly $x\notin\Bbb{K}$ in which case the arithmetic takes place in an extension $\Bbb{K}(x)$?